# Capturar errores de conexion con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

Tengo un carrusel de vídeos hecho en JQuery que hace una petición AJAX, entonces si llega a fallar el Internet el vídeo se detiene y ya no avanza el sistema y muestra estos errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo me preguntaba si habría alguna forma de capturar estos errores en JQuery y si se dan reinicie el carrusel?.

Comment: puedes hacer un try catch en javascript https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: agrega tu codigo jquery tambien puedes agregar una funcion onError

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el evento error del propio vídeo. Este evento puedes bindearlo a los  elementos vídeo con el atributo onerror , o por JavaScript ya sea con jQuery o JavaScript nativo.

```
<video onerror="miFuncion()">
```

Con jQuery

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('video').on('error',function(){
    //lo que quieras hacer aquí
  })
}); 
</script>
```

Con JavaScript nativo

```
<script>
  document.onload = function(){
      document.getElementsByTagName("VIDEO").onerror = function (){
          //lo que quieras hacer aquí
      };
  }
</script>
```